# How can I turn off Numba DEBUG messages in a Python project?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, numba, librosa

I'm working on a Python project with the Librosa sound editing library, which makes use of Numba.  Every time I call a Librosa function (in this case, pitch_shift), my PyCharm console window spits out literally thousands of lines of DEBUG messages, beginning with

```
DEBUG:numba.byteflow:bytecode dump:
           0    NOP(arg=None, lineno=10)
           2    LOAD_GLOBAL(arg=0, lineno=10)
           4    LOAD_CONST(arg=1, lineno=10)
           6    LOAD_FAST(arg=2, lineno=10)
                     ...
```

I've tried turning off the debugging messages using @jit(debug=False) and os.environ['NUMBA_DEBUG']='0', but neither of these seem to be the proper way of doing this.  Does anybody have experience with this, and might you lend me a hand?

Answer (score 6):

This worked in my case:

```
import librosa
import logging

logging.getLogger('numba').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, just make sure your calling code does not create any fancy logger. Go with just, say,

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the logging for debug Code, so it stops clogging up my logfiles:

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename=Logfilename, filemode='w') #instead of Level=logging.DEBUG`